# If else condition Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have documents like below format.

```
{
   "demo":{
      "sample1":"",
      "sample2":""
   },
   "hier":{
      "level10":"123",
      "level9":"456",
      "level8":"789",
      "level7":"012",
      "level6":"234",
      "level5":"345",
      "....""level2":"567",
      "level1":"678""relation":3
   }
}
```

Here i will get the all the hierarchy of a company, where i need to remove all level 1 and     level 2 from entire hierarchy when the relation is 3

```
    {
       "from":0,
       "size":100,
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "must":[
                {
                   "multi_match":{
                   ""//to bring the entire hierarchy"
                   }
                }
             ],
             "must_not":[
              {
               "match":{
                  "hier.level1": ""
                 }
              },
              {
               "match":{
                  "hier.level2": ""
               }
              }
            ]
         }
      }
}
```

Here i am unable to keep a condition that only when relation is 3 i need to exclude level 1 and level 2 values. Need help with the elastic query.

Comment: you need to have a nested field type for that. Please share your mapping and let me check
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: {"mapping" : { "properties" : "hier" : { "level10" : { "type": "text", "fields" : { "keyword" : { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256}}}, { "level2" : { "type": "text", "fields" : { "keyword" : { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256}}}, { "level1" : { "type": "text", "fields" : { "keyword" : { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256}}}, relation : { "type": "long"}}}

Comment: It looks like default mapping. Please use the nested field type, reindex the data, and use the nested query to achieve the result.